# Searchbar doesn't work with firefox

Tags: 2010, search, search-results, firefox

I have a trouble with the searchbar in sharepoint 2010. When searching with IE it works as it should but when using Chrome or Firefox the query adds  **`&amp;`**   instead of  **`&`**
resulting in that the searchbar doesnt recognise the query and returns an error "No search query specified".

```
IE

 search.aspx?cat=pro&k=Random Search Text

Firefox


 search.aspx?cat=pro&amp;k=Random Search Text
```

Where can I fix this problem and how?

Comment: is it a custom searchbar?

Comment: I was first told i wasn't and started searching for a problem on the Sharepoint-site. Later realising that is was a custom searchbar created by another developer. Fixed the problem by changing the searchquery (which was set to "&amp;") to "&". It seems IE did the right thing and Firefox didn't. Go figure :)

Comment: if I don't wrong the correct way to interprets your & is the Firefox's way, because it translate as a char not something to use to concat the string. SO IMHO you should fine the other way round: how to let IE and Chrome interprets correctly the & symbol

Comment: I changed the code to '&' and it works on all browsers now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is was a custom searchbar created by another developer. Fixed the problem by changing the searchquery (which was set to `&amp;`) to `&`. It seems IE did the right thing and Firefox didn't. Go figure :)